# Card game No-Got

Tags: identify-this-game

I was at a park in Florida and they were playing a game called No- got. they had two dice per person two decks of cards and you deal out all the cards and then you roll two dice and you followed the suit on your own pile.  if you could’nt play you put a nickel in does anyone know another name for this so I can find the rules